# Using setInterval on z-index to reveal images one by one

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, setinterval, z-index

I'm trying to use setInterval in Javascript to increase the z-index of images, therefore revealing an image and bringing each to the front one by one when hovering on a title. It currently only brings one image to the front...

Here's the JS:

```
const imageArea = document.querySelector('div.images')
const images = imageArea.querySelectorAll('img')
const performanceTag = document.querySelector('a.performance')

let currentImage = 0
let zCount = 0

performanceTag.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  
  setInterval(function() {
    currentImage =+ 1
    zCount =+ 1
  }, 1000)
  

    images[currentImage].style.zIndex = `${zCount}`
})
```

Here's the HTML :

```
<section class="container">
  <section class="column1">
    <a href="#" class="performance 1">Performance One</a>
    <a href="#" class="performance 2">Performance Two</a>
    <a href="#" class="performance 3">Performance Three</a>
  </section>

  <section class="column2">
    <div class="images">
      <img src="cat-questions-08.gif" />
      <img src="cat-begging-cute.gif" />
      <img src="1800x1200_why_cats_sneeze_ref_guide.jpg" />
      <img src="cat-sad-cat.gif" />
      <img src="131117-wd-cats.jpg" />
    </div>
  </section>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
a.performance {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

section.column2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
}

img  {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You only add the event listener to the first link. `document.querySelector` returns the first element found. Try `document.querySelectorAll` and iterate over the nodes.

Comment: There's a classic memory leak there.

Comment: Hey Zsolt, thanks - you're right, I did only add the event listener for the first link. Wanted to get it working before scaling up and attempting to add a different set of images for each link. But I see how that's confusing... Either way, that shouldn't affect the function, should it?

And Keith, thanks, I hadn't heard of a memory leak before, that was good to read about! Not sure how I stop the leak still though sadly